# PHP Loop - How to run the same function get different random numbers

Tags: php, loops

I have a function that generates 6 random numbers (00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00) multiple times in the loop. Before it generates the second and third sequence I'd like this function to check whether the previous sequences are different so I do not repeat the same sequence again. Can you help me with it?

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= $qde; $x++) {

ger(); 

}
```

Comment: paste the code form ger()

Comment: You can use recursion to achieve it

Comment: In what range are your numbers? Below 100?

Comment: @Victor: ok, with 60 numbers there are 50063860 ways to choose six of them. While it's possible for your function to return the same sequence twice,  it's far less likely than your server being hit by a Klingon rocket from the outer space.

Comment: ahaha !! Thanks @georg that's a nice answer !!

Comment: @georg what if I work on a range of 01 to 08? I mean because the range will change. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way:

1. Generate the random values and place them in an array
2. Run `array_unique()` on the array to see if they are unique and place the unique values in a new array (or overwrite the existing array): http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php
3. If not all values are unique (compare count of unique array to your desired number of values), run the random value generator again for however many more numbers you need, and attach them to your array.
4. Repeat 2 and 3 as necessary.

Comment: Thanks @Ynhockey I've been doing it on ger() function to generate the sequences of 6. But as the function runs multiple times in the loop I want to make sure the following sequences are not equal to the previous

Comment: If you post the code for ger() in your original question it might be possible to suggest changes, but basically without knowing what it does, I would recommend that it return something, not just run as a procedure. Maybe it can return that array I was talking about.